# Template Classes in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I would like to make it so that when I open a new java class file in a certain package it opens the file with some pre-written lines of code. How would I do this? I researched on the web for solutions but I couldn't find any, google talked about VTL code but I didn't understand https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by right clicking and going under new and then going under edit file templates this was able to make my own file templates